# Sorting an array of objects in Ruby by object attribute?

Tags: ruby, sorting, object

I have an array of objects in Ruby on Rails. I want to sort the array by an attribute of the object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 269):

I recommend using sort_by instead:

```
objects.sort_by {|obj| obj.attribute}
```

Especially if attribute may be calculated.

Or a more concise approach:

```
objects.sort_by(&:attribute)
```

Comment: Or the shorthand version: `objects.sort_by(&:attribute)`

Comment: even more shorter objects.sort_by &:attribute

Comment: If you have problems with uppercase & lowercase letters being sorted separately, you can use `objects.sort_by { |obj| obj.attribute.downcase }`

Comment: Any idea how this compares with `sort!` (e.g. speed, etc.)?

Comment: [Enumerable#sort_by docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

Answer (score 37):

Yes, using [`Array#sort!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002209) this is easy.

```
myarray.sort! { |a, b|  a.attribute <=> b.attribute }
```

Comment: Thnx buddy
but it didn't work out for me
i have an array of objects. In which one of the attribute of the object is created_at.
I want to sort it with this field. so i did  
@comm_bytes.sort! {|a, b|  a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
but no luck for me
can u help....??

Comment: Is there a created_at method to access the @created_at attribute? What kind of object is @created_at?  Does it define `<=>`?  What kind of errors are you getting?  etc, etc, ad nauseum.  In other words, we need more detail than "but no luck for me".

Comment: it works if you do myarray = myarray.sort {...}    without "!"

Comment: @Doru Yes, that works too, but why would you do that? It’s less direct and less efficient. Use `sort` if you want to preserve the original and assign the result to a different object; otherwise, use the in-place variant, `sort!`. In fact, `sort` calls `sort!` internally, after copying the original object.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know it sounds crazy but I spent a lot of time trying to sort my array and to my surprise myarray.sort!  didn't do the job but this way did ... strange

Comment: @Doru There must be an error somewhere else in the code, I can 100% guarantee you that `sort!` will work just fine, and always (!) do the same thing as what you’ve written.

Comment: @Konrad I get:  undefined method `sort!' for #     any suggestion what I should look at?

Comment: @DoruChidean That’s bizarre — are you sure that your collection is an *array*, rather than some other object? If so, your Ruby installation is broken and you should reinstall it.

Answer (score 37):

Ascending order :

```
objects_array.sort! { |a, b|  a.attribute <=> b.attribute }
```

or

```
objects_array.sort_by{ |obj| obj.attribute }
```

Descending order :

```
objects_array.sort! { |a, b|  b.attribute <=> a.attribute }
```

or

```
objects_array.sort_by{ |obj| obj.attribute }.reverse
```

Answer (score 21):

in case you need sorting by two attributes, where first one is more important then second (means taking in account second arguments only if first arguments are equal), then you may do like this

```
myarray.sort{ |a,b| (a.attr1 == b.attr1) ? a.attr2 <=> b.attr2 : a.attr1 <=> b.attr1 }
```

or in case of array of arrays

```
myarray.sort{ |a,b| (a[0] == b[0]) ? a[1] <=> b[1] : a[0] <=> b[0] }
```

Answer (score 19):

You can make any class sortable by overriding the <=> method:

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @last_name + @first_name <=> other.last_name + other.first_name
  end

end
```

Now an array of Person objects will be sortable on last_name.

```
ar = [Person.new("Eric", "Cunningham"), Person.new("Homer", "Allen")]

puts ar  # => [ "Eric Cunningham", "Homer Allen"]  (Person objects!)

ar.sort!

puts ar  # => [ "Homer Allen", "Eric Cunningham" ]
```

Comment: This (overriding `<=>`) is what I was looking for, thanks.  One suggestion, though: Instead of sorting by (abbreviating for space) `last + first` (with string concatenation), maybe sort by `[last, first]` (making an array -- and let ruby's `sort` work out the groupings under the covers).  May not matter in most cases, but imagine the case of comparing "Stephen Mac", "Alice Mac", and "Billy MacGregor".  With array-based sorting, the "Mac"s will stay together.  With string-based, they get split up.

Answer (score 12):

More elegant `objects.sort_by(&:attribute)`, you can add on a `.reverse` if you need to switch the order.

Answer (score 10):

Array#sort works well, as posted above:

```
myarray.sort! { |a, b|  a.attribute <=> b.attribute }
```

BUT, you need to make sure that the `<=>` operator is implemented for that attribute. If it's a Ruby native data type, this isn't a problem. Otherwise, write you own implementation that returns -1 if a < b, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if a > b.

Answer (score -2):

Yes its possible

http://ariejan.net/2007/01/28/ruby-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-an-attribute/

Answer (score -2):

```
@model_name.sort! { |a,b| a.attribute <=> b.attribute }
```

Comment: There are plenty of identical answers posted in 2009. No need to add another one.

Comment: Don't use `sort` when you are sorting objects that can't be directly compared. If you have to access attributes or do a computation to get the value to compare use `sort_by`. It will be much faster.